# Showing web service's input values in autocompletetextview in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am consuming one web service right now.This web service will return some string values if i give proper input values.Here my requirement is, i need to show these input values in AutoCompleteTextView in android.

*For example:*

Assume my web service is having the input values such as,
"AX","AB","B","CC","CX","D" and so on.Here i need to show these input values in AutocompleteTextView in android.

**NOTE:** I don't want to do hard-code these input values in string format in AutoCompleteTextView, because these input values will be updated day by day.So that there will be no meaning of hard-codding it,is it not?

suggestions please!

thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you can get data from your service in the form of string data.

```
public String getDataFromService()
{
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(yourserviceURLgoeshere);
        HttpResponse httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is=entity.getContent();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return parseExecutedRequest();
}

private String parseExecutedRequest()
{
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;

        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line+ "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: then when you get the data in the form of string.
It may be xml or json string
break that string into array or in other words store the data into an arraylist as sujit is saying.
then set the arrayy adapter of autocomplete box to this arraylistadapter you have created from the string u got from service.

i hope u get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ArrayList and fill the data you get form web service and set adapter to the **AutoCompleteTextView**  with the **ArrayList** you have created.

Comment: @Kalpeash yes i know bro..creating ArryList from web service data is not hard code. It's obviously dynamic.

Comment: @Sujit don't mistake me,i cannot get you bro,because i am newbie to android,in-fact i am self learner to android too..do you have any example for this?

Comment: there is nothing related to Android except AutoCompleteTextView here. Its all core java.You just have to parse the data that you are getting from web service and build your arraylist that's all and pass the data to the adapter of the AutoComplateTextView. I don't have any exact implementation right now with me but its a comment implementation in any web service related project. better you search for a web service example and try to find how to to configure your ArrayList. hope u can get me.

Answer (score 0):

in this you to make array if input values and bind it on AutoCompleteTextView. here is the example [click this](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/autocompletetextview-example.html)

Comment: Your example is just hard coding the values in autocompletetextview,but i don't want to do like so,because i am going to show only the input values of a web service's in AutoCompleteTextView in android

Comment: to bind data in autocomplete textview you must have harcoded array or make an array from webservice...